Biztalk 2020 File format is not valid. (System.Windows.Forms) during choosing filter to configure
I cannot configure filters for any Sendport on the specific BizTalk host. Choosing any Filter gets me the following error:
File format is not valid. (System.Windows.Forms)

On the second host in the same BizTalk group everything is OK.
Are there any environment settings I should check? I checked Regional settings and dates - everything looks the same on both hosts


It take it isn't a clustered environment? e.g. two hosts and DB.    Try deleting BizTalk applications one by one (backing them up first) and trying again.  I'd suspect a corruption of some sort in one of the binding files is causing an issue

If Binding was corrupted why it works on the second Host then?

Maybe it got corrupted during/after import.   What was the last change you did before it stopped working?

I don't know because many people are working on it.
It is even more strange - I cannot create a new send port with any filter - choosing the filter name causes crash instantly .

I've only had something similar to that happen once in a Dev environment, many years ago, and deleting BizTalk Apps until it worked again is how I solved that.

Is there any possibility different version of System.Windows.Forms on the two servers? Where one is more lax in deserializing the configuration?
